# Animate NSTextField Alignment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to emulate the functionality of the Safari url text field (using NSTextField).  I'd like the current text to be displayed centered, but when the user clicks on it the text should highlight and slide to the left.  I've got the highlighting working but I'm not sure how to go about animating the text over to the left.  Is it possible to animate the Alignment property or would I need to do some sort of custom drawing where I animate the position that the text is drawn?

Unfortunately this ([Is there a way to animate changing a UILabel's textAlignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251506/is-there-a-way-to-animate-changing-a-uilabels-textalignment)) won't work, since a text field draws a background and border so animating the frame isn't an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to animate changing a UILabel's textAlignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251506/is-there-a-way-to-animate-changing-a-uilabels-textalignment)

Comment: Ugh, I messed up on flagging this. This is a duplicate of this — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228378/animate-a-change-with-nstextalignment-of-uitextfield-using-swift — and if you follow the link in the answer given it may give you an idea how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate a change with NSTextAlignment of UITextField using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228378/animate-a-change-with-nstextalignment-of-uitextfield-using-swift)