# UITextfield text position not animating while width constraint is animated

Tags: ios, animation, uitextfield, width, ios10

I have three UITextField aligned in a container used to choose a date.

At first only the month textfield is shown in the container and takes the full width, then when the user chose the month, the day textfield appear and they both take half of the container.

The text alignement in these textfields is centered.

My problem is that when I animate their size, **the text doesn't animate and jumps directly to the final position while the width of the textfields animate correctly**.

Step 1 : The TextField Before Animation
[image: Step 1 : The TextField Before Animation]

Step 2 : The TexField width is animating but the text is already in the final position
[image: Step 2 : The TexField width is animating but the text is already in the final position]

Step 3 : The TexField Finished Animating
[image: Step 3 : The TexField Finished Animating]

My code used to animate the constraint :

```
monthTextfieldTrailingConstraint.priority = currentDateSelectionType == .month ? UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh : UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
dayTextfieldTrailingConstraint.priority = currentDateSelectionType == .day ? UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh : UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
yearTextfieldTrailingConstraint.priority = currentDateSelectionType == .year ? UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh : UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow

UIView.animate(withDuration: nextStepAnimationDuration) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: @shallowThought I know I'm a few months late, but please take a look at my answer. Thanks

Comment: @ZionPerez I guess you meant Matthias, not me. :-)

Comment: @shallowThought :) Yes you and Matthias. I thought you may have had the same question since you edited it, but maybe not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had almost the exact same question. Please see my question and its answer for reference: [UITextField text jumps when animating width constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096578/uitextfield-text-jumps-when-animating-width-constraint)

**Solution Demo**

The solution is to embed your textfields within another view (e.g. another UITextField or a UIView). In the gif below, I put a textfield within a textfield. Note that `helloWorldTextField` has a blue border to show its location within the second textfield behind it.

[image]

**Instructions**

1. For each field (month, day), make two textfields, e.g. `monthTextField` and `monthBorderTextField`.
2. Remove `monthTextField`'s border and background color. Keep `borderTextField`'s border and background color.
3. Center `monthTextField` within `borderTextField`.
4. Animate the width of `borderTextField` as needed.

**Github link and Code**

Here is the link to my project on Github: https://github.com/starkindustries/ConstraintAnimationTest

Here is the code for my test project for my MyViewController class. Everything else is setup in the storyboard which can be viewed on Github at the link above.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // Hello World TextField Border var
    @IBOutlet weak var borderTextFieldWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // Button Vars
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    var grow: Bool = false

    func animateGrowShrinkTextFields(grow: Bool, duration: TimeInterval) {
        if grow {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.borderTextFieldWidth.constant = 330
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                print("Grow animation complete!")
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.borderTextFieldWidth.constant = 115
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                print("Shrink animation complete!")
            })
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toggle(){
        let duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
        grow = !grow
        let title = grow ? "Shrink" : "Grow"
        myButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)
        animateGrowShrinkTextFields(grow: grow, duration: duration)
    }
}
```

**Notes and References**

What led me to this solution was @JimmyJames's comment: "You are just animating the UITextField width, but the content inside is not animated."

I researched how to animate font changes and came across this question: [Is there a way to animate changing a UILabel's textAlignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251506/is-there-a-way-to-animate-changing-a-uilabels-textalignment)

In that question @CSmith mentioned that "you can animate the FRAME, not the textAlignment" https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251634/2179970

The accepted answer in that question suggests to use a UILabel within another frame. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251735/2179970

Comment: Until Apple fixes that I'll go with this solution thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)